# Why can't I add Firebase into an existing Project?

Tags: javascript, firebase-hosting

I have been recently introduced to Firebase and I have tried to implement its functionality to my so called "website", which is written in HTML(Bootstrap)/CSS and no JS. There are several pages and the whole thing is basically in preview mode, because it doesn't have real functionality. So.. For the past several days, I am trying to implement firebase with 0 luck. Is it not working because I am not using Angular or React.js?

So far to my knowledge I followed every step necessary to be able to use firebase, but whenever I use "firebase deploy" or "firebase deploy --only hosting" and click on the project link it shows only my homepage with broken CSS and invalid links. I can't navigate to login/sign up screen or anything of that sort and I don't understand the problem since everything works just fine if I view it on Live Server.

In short, when I "firebase deploy" and view the page, I see a page with Broken CSS and if I try to click on for example "Products" I get a 404 page. Login/Sign up buttons don't even work.

Console Error
[image]

I have a "app.js" file with

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-analytics.js";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  my info
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

and have a source link on my index.html <script type="module" src="/public/app.js"></script>.
To my knowledge this should be enough since I followed the official tutorial and that's how they write it, but clearly I am doing something wrong..

my node -v
v18.14.1

and npm -v
9.3.1

I'd be glad to add any other documentation needed to assist, but since I am clearly new to this, I don't really know what else to add.

Comment: Open console and read the errors

Comment: Thanks, I have added the console, but it only makes things more confusing to me, hope this helps though

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this helps anyone who is going to face the same problem just as I did.

After a very long time I have finally found that my problem was in the "href", by that I mean that I would link like `<a href="/website/index.html"></a>` and this would cause the firebase to throw an error as it could not find the index file. What fixed the problem was linking the file like `<a href="index.html"></a>` or better explained, starting the link without the forward slash.

Also CSS/JS files have to be in their own separate folders and linked accordingly `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`